# Google Plus on iOS - GPPSignIn authenticate always prompts for consent

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-oauth, google-authentication

We have a server on which we sign up with these parameters:

```
<button  id="su-googlebtn" class="btn btn-social btn-lg g-signin"
             data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read"
             data-clientid=WEBCLIENTID
             data-redirecturi="postmessage"
             data-accesstype="offline"
             data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
             data-callback="signInGoogle">
        <i id="googleicon" class="fa fa-google-plus redicon"></i> Google+
    </button>
```

I've authed my google account against this server.  The consent it asks for is

- Know who you are on Google
- View your email addresses

Now in the iOS app, I use these parameters:

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
        signIn.homeServerClientID = WEBCLIENTID;
        signIn.clientID = APPCLIENTID;
        signIn.scopes = @[ @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" ];
```

Any time I sign in to the same account on the app using authenticate, it bumps me out to the web and asks for consent to "Have offline access". If I have google plus installed, it bumps me out to that instead and asks for consent for the same as the web. My question is, after calling `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut]`, with `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate]` always prompt for new consent? This doesn't make much sense to me as they've already consented. The secondary question is why are the consents in google plus vs safari/chrome different?

Note: trySilentAuthentication works as expected and gives me a idToken that I can send to the server for verification.

Second Note: We do not need to make any API calls from the client, only the server, so all we really need on the client side is an ID token that we can use to authenticate the user on our server. Should we be just using a UIWebview to do the auth instead of the native GPPSignIn library?